# Amount of BizTalk Orphaned Instances that starts noticeable performance degradation

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-2013

What is the acceptable amount of Orphaned Instances before you start to notice performance degradation of the BizTalk server?

Comment: 1) As it is not a programming question it is probably of topic for Stack Overflow, it might belong on https://serverfault.com/ , however  2) It is probably a cumulative effect 3) It would depend on the performance of the BizTalk environment to start off with.   So probably no fixed answer.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf Unfortunately, there's a whopping 30 BizTalk questions on SF.  The last one asked 1.5 years ago. :()

Comment: @Johns-305  Yes, I know. And they don't tend to get answered there either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, let me answer it this way.  The acceptable number of orphaned instances is 0.  Meaning, this shouldn't be happening, and if it is, it's a problem to solve.

The answer to your actual question is...it depends.  Depends on your database and app profiles.

Make sure the SQL Jobs are all running without error, then identify the app that is creating the orphans and refactor it to not do that.